# checkbox styling with css

Tags: css, checkbox, styling

I would like to remove the white space between the original border of the checkbox and the boxshadow, so that it looks at least compact.

```
float: right;
    padding: 0px;   
    -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.01);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    -o-transform: scale(1.1);
     margin-right: 2px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px white, 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px white, 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 5px #dedede, 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
```

What can I do ?

Best regards

Comment: Which browser? Form control styles vary widely.

Comment: for all(chrome, ie, firefox) browsers, would be nice.